# Cartesian product of smooth maps is smooth

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g \in C^\infty(X)$.  I would like to show that $f \times g \in C^\infty(X \times X)$. This seems obvious, but I'm not sure how to actually prove it. I was thinking of using projection maps $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: What do you mean by f x g?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca If we index our product space as $X_1 \times X_2$, then $(f \times g)(X_1 \times X_2) = f(X_1) \times g(X_2)$.

Comment: Is $X$ a manifold?

Comment: @Meneer-Beer I originally saw this problem in the contexts of manifolds, so I suppose so. I wonder if it holds more generally as well.

Comment: The charts in $X\times X$ are the products of the charts from $X$. So locally we have a chart where $f$ is smooth and a $g$ is smooth. Then the product of these charts is a chart in $X\times X$ for $(f,g)$

Comment: @Meneer-Beer Suppose $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ are two charts in $X$. Then $(U \times V, \phi \times \psi)$ is a chart in $X \times X$, this part is clear. But now to prove that is is a smooth manifold, we need to show that for any two charts in $X \times X$, let's say $(U \times V, \phi \times \psi)$ and $(W \times Z, \eta \times \varphi)$, we have to show that the maps $(\phi \times \psi) \circ (\eta \times \varphi)^{-1} = (\phi \circ \eta^{-1}) \times (\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}) $ are smooth.

Comment: @Meneer-Beer However, we know that each of the factors $f = \phi \circ \eta^{-1}$ and $g = \psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ are smooth, so the problem reduces to show that $f \times g$ is smooth. This is that I am trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write $f \times g \in C^{\infty}(X \times X, \mathbb{R}^2)$. Use the definition of smooth, which says that we have to check that given any $(p, q) \in X \times X$, the coordinate representation of $f \times g$ on some coordinate patch $U \ni (p, q)$ is smooth. Pick neighborhoods $U \ni p$ and $V \ni q$ and charts $\phi : O_x \to U$ and $\psi : \Omega_y \to V$, where $O$ and $\Omega$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. then the coordinate representation of $f \times g$ wrt the chart $\phi \times \psi : O \times \Omega \to U \times V$ is $((f \times g) \circ \phi \times \psi)(x, y) = (f(\phi(x)), g(\psi(y)))$. Now by assumption that $f, g$ are smooth, $f^x = f \circ \phi : O \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g^y = g \circ \psi : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth. By the formula $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (f^x(x), g^y(y)) = (\partial_{x_j}f^x(x), g^y(y))$$
and other analogous formulas and the fact that a $\mathbb{R}^k$ valued function is smooth if and only if all it's components are smooth, we have $f^x \times g^y \in C^{\infty}(O \times \Omega, \mathbb{R}^2)$ as desired.

Comment: I see, so basically the key point used here is that a cartesian product is smooth if and only if all component are smooth?

Comment: @CBBAM Yeah. Sometimes that is taken as the definition of smooth, but if you use Frechet derivatives to define smoothness, then it is an easy theorem that a function $F : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if each component $F_i : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x$

Comment: Got it, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

By definition of $f\times g$ we get that

$f\times g=\alpha \circ (f,g)$

where $\alpha \colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ sends $(x,y)\to xy$ and $(f,g)\colon X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^2$ sends $(p,q)$ to $(f(p), g(q))$.

Of course $\alpha $ is smooth.

Regarding $(f,g)$, the map is smooth if and only if its factors $\pi_i\circ (f,g)\colon X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth, where $\pi_i\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection map.

Moreover you can prove that $\pi_1\circ (f,g) $ is smooth if and only if $f$ is smooth (the same holds for $\pi_2\circ (f,g)$ and $g$).

Hence, under you assumption of smoothness of $f$ and $g$, then $f\times g$ is smooth.

Comment: In your proof it seems you are taking $f \times g$ to be a map from $X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? My apologies if my wording was unclear, but I am looking for the case where $f \times g: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CBBAM uhhh, yeah I’m sorry, I haven’t got it